# What is the difference between ODE and scalar differential equation?

Tags: differential

Can someone please explaine what scalar diffrential equation mean? What is the difference between ODE and scalar differential equation?

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some context for this, e.g. saying where you saw each term used.

Comment: Terminology questions are on-topic here, and my standards for how much context is needed are minimal for these.  However the use of a phrase like "scalar differential equation" (if it is to be contrasted with use of a different phrase) needs a point of reference.  Different authors might use different phrases to mean the same thing, or they might use the same phrase to mean different things.  So cite where you saw the phrases you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

An ODE is a differential equation consisting of one or more functions of one independent variable and their derivatives.

A scalar differential equation is a differential equation consisting of one function of one or more independent variables and their derivatives/partial derivatives.

Thus an ODE may not be scalar equation.
For example: System of ODE given by
\begin{eqnarray}
u'(t)=f(t)\\
v'(t)=g(t)
\end{eqnarray}

On the other hand a scalar equation need not be an ODE.
For example : $$u_t+au_x=0$$